# retroarch Error while read-only file system

Tags: snap, read-only, mkdir

I installed a snap of retroarch. When i run,it show below error in image

```
fazil@acer:~$ retroarch
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/fazil/snap/retroarch’: Read-only file system
```

[retroarch error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QWM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did this, and it helped: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/retroarch-help-with-issue-on-first-launch/9869

We need to properly raise it in their bug tracker, I'll try to do that